# "Way to travel" or "Way of travel"

Tags: prepositions

Which sentence is more grammatically correct?

- Welcome to a new way **to** travel
- Welcome to a new way **of** travel

(We are promoting our airport service which allows one to avoid stepping foot inside the airport to get to their commercial flight. )

Answer (score 0):

"Way of travel" tends to mean "route used for the purpose of travelling from one point to another.

([A History of Travel in America - Seymour Dunbar p. 163· 2008](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/A_History_of_Travel_in_America_vol_1/iwtdAgAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22way+of+travel%22&pg=PA163&printsec=frontcover)) He says: “It required a mind of far more than ordinary calibre to locate through more than two hundred miles of mountain wilderness a way of travel which, for a hundred years, has remained practically unchanged, and upon which the state ...

([The Book of Isaiah - Page 212 - Edward J. Young · 1992](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Book_of_Isaiah/b7yar62dYg0C?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22way+of+travel%22&pg=PA212&printsec=frontcover)) The way of the righteous is straight , because God smoothes it out , removing from it whatever obstacles may stand in the way of travel . Herein is taught a principle of divine providence , namely , that the way of the righteous is in

In these next references, it has the sense of "means" (of transportation).

([Internal Revenue Acts of the United States, 1909-1950: ...Bernard D. Reams · 1979](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Internal_Revenue_Acts_of_the_United_Stat/M9wmAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22way+of+travel%22&pg=PA1036&printsec=frontcover)) It becomes a much more economical way of travel , , but not a good way of travel . Mr. REED . It is a more dangerous way of travel . Mr. MANTLER . That is right .

([Slow Travel and Tourism - Page 108 Janet E. Dickinson, ‎Les Lumsdon · 2010](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Slow_Travel_and_Tourism/_qEYqgeLbmwC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22way+of+travel%22&pg=PA108&printsec=frontcover)) The decline of the railway as a form of transport and consequently as a way of travel for the tourist has been more or less relentless in many countries throughout the latter part of the 20th century.

There might even be one more meaning, which is not found in the page
" https://www.google.com/search?q=%22way%20of%20travel%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en ", I believe; it can be understood from the following example.

- As you are frequently on the move from city to city, from one country to another, you are bound to make new acquaintances, learn new things, find more pleasure to life than otherwise, but as well you incur certain risks that impel you to think about contracting various types of insurance, theft and life insurance for the most important ones; that is the way of travel. (user LPH's example)

> (**SOED**) **12a** […] ;the course of events in the occurrence of something.

Therefore,  "way of travel"  cannot mean "manner of travelling" too obviously. If the verb form were changed (*way of travelling*), then  there' would be no doubt as to  this expression being as good as "*way **to** travel*" meaning "manner of travelling". Therefore I'd choose the preposition "to".

Comment: Wait what? How were you able to answer this?

Comment: @Heartspring I suppose there is mechanism that allows posting when the answer has been started a sufficiently long time before the time of closure; otherwise I don't know.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you so much.